# INSERT INTO したときに一意制約違反のエラーが出る

Tags: sql

sql文を使って、table1からtable2にflagの情報を追加したいときに、
table1の中の
flag = '1'の場合、'1'を設定
flag = '0'の場合、nullを設定
がしたいですが

```
insert into table2 select pk1,pk2,pk3,(case when flag='1' then '1' else null end) as col1 from table1
```

を実行するときに、aはPRIMARY KEYではありませんが、一意制約違反のエラーが出ます。
どうにもうまくできませんでした。

table1とtable2の構成について

```
CREATE TABLE table1
pk1                       CHAR(13) NOT NULL,
pk2                       NUMBER(3,0) NOT NULL,
pk3                       CHAR(13) NOT NULL,
flag                      CHAR(1),
etc．．．
CONSTRAINT PK_table1 PRIMARY KEY (CUST_NUM, CUST_SEQ, REC_NUM) USING INDEX
```

table1とtable2の構成が一緒で、table2に前期のデータと今期（table1）のデータを入れたいです。

初めて質問するので不足しているところが多々あると思いますが、
どなたがご教授いただければ幸いです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: table1 およびtable2のテーブルの情報（create table）と実際に入っているデータ（Insert）もいただけるとより回答が付きやすいと思います。

Comment: わかりました。編集してみます。ご意見ありがとうございます。

Comment: 実際に入っているデータの情報がないので何が一意制約に引っかかっているのかがわかりませんが、PK_table1 primary keyで設定されているデータでtable2と重複しているものはありませんか？

Comment: ありがちですよね。私の場合一時的に「一意制約」を外し、重複したままデータを入れたあとに重複データを調べるようにしています。外すことできない状況もあるかとおもいますが、その場合同じ構成の別テーブルを一時的に作成し重複データを調べるとよいです。